# Automaticly include all scripts from target folder in runned script - CS6

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to `#include` all scripts from target folder **dynamically** in the runned script. Without any need of **writing out** each script **name/path**, each time. 
That's mean:
 => you drop any script into target folder => when you run script, scripts/script from target are automatically included to the runned script.

EDIT: You can also invoke any functions or variable from injected piece of code in any scope.

I wrote this script so far:

```
var runnedScriptPath = $.fileName;
var runnedScriptFolderPath = getScriptFolder(runnedScriptPath);

var targetScriptsFolderPath = runnedScriptFolderPath + "/foo";
var targetScriptsFolder = Folder(targetScriptsFolderPath);

includeScriptsFromTargetFolder(targetScriptsFolder);

function includeScriptsFromTargetFolder(targetFolder) {

    var targetFolderFiles = targetFolder.getFiles();

    var scriptFilesToInclude = new Array;

    for (var i = 0; i < targetFolderFiles.length; i++) {
        if (targetFolderFiles[i] instanceof File) {
            if (targetFolderFiles[i].toString().match(/.jsx$/)) { // .jsx is extension from Adobe's scripts
                scriptFilesToInclude.push(decodeURIComponent(targetFolderFiles[i]) ); // decodeURIComponent method is used becouse path is URl
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < scriptFilesToInclude.length; i++) {
        #include scriptFilesToInclude[i]; // <=====  this line gives error!
    }

}

function getScriptFolder(scriptPath) {
    return scriptPath.match(/^(.*[\\\/])/g); // match(/^(.*[\\\/])/g) "Select everything before the last forward slash" //
}
```

But then I got this error:
[image]

I couldn't find any reasonable solution in [javascript tools guide cs6.pdf](https://github.com/1179432578/psd-tool/blob/master/JavaScript%20Tools%20Guide%20CS6.pdf) in chapter "Preprocessor directives", page 235.

My reasoning is:
 `scriptFilesToInclude[i]` outcome is string, so it should be treated as `"some path/runned code folder/foo/bar.jsx"`. And then string path be loaded to the script. But instead of it, I suppose it tried to find a file in runned script's folder named: `scriptFilesToInclude[i]`.

==============================================================

Notes:

I tried to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):
`eval("#include scriptFiles[i]");`
And also [JSON.pars()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):
`JSON.parse("#include scriptFiles[i]");`
To bypass error, but it didn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I see I get downvotes, can anyone says what is wrong with this question?

Comment: The question is well formatted. I don't know why you are getting downvotes. I just want to point that `#include` is not a JavaScript keyword. Is a specific keyword from the engine you are using. I guess that it does a static analysis and do not includes the script dynamically. it just gets the string after `#include` and loads it. Being a specific weird engine I guess that is not going to be an easy task to have dynamic inclused, if possible.

Comment: "Being a specific weird engine I guess that is not going to be an easy task to have dynamic inclused". Btw. If someone gives answer that sth is impossible to do and he proofs it, then by stackoverflow's standards problem is solved or not?

Comment: yeah yeah, of course, don't get me wrong. I mean, I've seen a lot of questions without an answer here, and this one seems pretty hard to find someone, nothing more haha. By the way, seems that there's someone that knows what he talks about below there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sergey Kritskiy has mentioned earlier it has to be used `$.evalFile()` function. 
But it is needed to be invoked in global scope, to has abilities to upload variable or function from included file anywhere where you need.

Code:

```
var runnedScriptPath = $.fileName;
var runnedScriptFolderPath = getScriptFolder(runnedScriptPath);

var targetScriptsFolderPath = runnedScriptFolderPath + "/foo";
var targetScriptsFolder = Folder(targetScriptsFolderPath);

var scriptsToInclude = includeScriptsFromTargetFolder(targetScriptsFolder);

for (var i = 0; i < scriptsToInclude.length; i++) { 
    $.evalFile(scriptsToInclude[i]); // <========= this function has to be invoked in global scope
}

function includeScriptsFromTargetFolder(targetFolder) {

    var targetFolderFiles = targetFolder.getFiles();

    var scriptFilesToInclude = new Array;

    for (var i = 0; i < targetFolderFiles.length; i++) {
        if (targetFolderFiles[i] instanceof File) {
            if (targetFolderFiles[i].toString().match(/.jsx$/)) { // .jsx is extension from Adobe's scripts
                scriptFilesToInclude.push(decodeURIComponent(targetFolderFiles[i]) ); // decodeURIComponent method is used becouse path is URl
            }
        }
    }

    return scriptFilesToInclude;
}

function getScriptFolder(scriptPath) {

    return scriptPath.match(/^(.*[\\\/])/g); // match(/^(.*[\\\/])/g) "Select everything before the last forward slash" //
}
```

Comment: It needs to be invoked in the same scope you want to use functions/variables: the same rule that’s applied everywhere in js.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$.evalFile()` instead of `eval()`:

```
$.evalFile(scriptFiles[i]);
```

Comment: Ok, it works at first glance, but it wasn't that what I asked exactly. Maybe question wasn't precise enough (I made edit for that reason). What I tested and according to the documentation on page 219. $.evalFile() **execute** script and returns the **result of evaluation**. Not the script itself. You can't use functions and variables from that script later.

Comment: Yes, you can. This will execute the script and all its functions will be available. https://prnt.sc/qweqpq Using `#include` with dynamic variables won't work though.

Comment: Ok, I tested and it works in example which you wrote, but it doesn't in mine (it still doesn't find var or function). [images](https://imgur.com/a/Fx0CGjb), [files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4mfbwye7lm94v91/AAAGc0JP_ciDMT0FEvc7WBzDa?dl=0). It sounds that there are some kind of scope issues.

Comment: Ok, when I took it from function, it has started working. So it was scope issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept then for others to find the answer quicker.